# Strictly monotonic continuous function?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Are there any continuous, strictly monotonic functions mapping $(0,1]$ to $(0,1)$? I think such functions map open sets to open sets and closed sets to closed sets. Am I correct??

Comment: There can be continuous, strictly monotonic functions from (0,1] to (0,1/2]. For example, f(x) = x/2.

Comment: You just answered your own question. Maybe you want to add surjective to your assumptions.

Comment: But (0,1] is neither closed nor open. What about mapping of such sets?

Comment: (0,1] can be union of (0,1) and [1]. So Will its mapping  be union of an open set and a closed set?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose to the contrary that there exists such a function $f:(0,1] \to (0,1)$. Since $f$ is continuous and strictly monotone, it is one-one and open. Also by assumption, it is onto, hence invertible with a continuous inverse, i.e. it is a homeomorphism. This is impossible because $1 = f^{-1}(a)$ for some $a\in (0,1)$, but $a$ is a cut point and $1$ is not a cut point.

Simpler argument:

$f$ is one-one because it's strictly monotone, so it is a bijection $(0,1] \to (0,1)$. Now $f((0,1)) = (0,1) - f(1)$ should be connected because $f$ is continuous, but this is impossible.

Comment: How is continuous strictly monotonic function open?

Comment: @jnyan the set $\mathcal I = \{(a,b)\cap (0,1], a < b\} $ is a basis for $(0,1]$'s topology. It suffices then to check that for $I \in \cal I$, $f(I)$ is an open subinterval of $(0,1)$

Comment: +1. This is a fine answer; the downvote is unwarranted even if it was for the original, more concise version of the answer.